# How to create many-to-many relationship in Express?

Tags: database, typescript, express

I'm writing a small API using Express and TypeScript. I have a POST request and a GET request. With POST request I get in a list of organizations, who might have daughter organizations, and the daughters might also have daughters, etc.

Im thinking of creating 2 db tables in postgreSQL. Organization and Parent_child.

```
Organization{
   id: number,
   name: string
}

Parent_child{
    parent_id: number,
    child_id: number
}
```

I'd like to create many-to-many relation from Organization to Organization through Parent_child. I have spend hours to understand how to use DB and most tutorials are vague at best.

Any suggestions on how to do it or what module to use for this? I have read about sequelize and typeORM but tutorials and manuals for them don't help me much.

Comment: What database? This isn't Express's job, it's down the the database interface or ORM. And library recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: What Johnrsharpe is also saying is that Express' job is really just handing and organizing a HTTP server and HTTP requests. Typically other tools are used for the database layer , so it doesn't make that much sense to even mention express in this question. Sequalize and TypeORM are good choices though, as is not using an ORM at all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe edited the question to include databasetype Postgresql.

Comment: Point stands, you need to read up on the database interface and/or ORM. Why exactly don't tutorials and manuals for the tools you're using to do this not help?

Comment: @jonrsharpe the ones i have been able to find leave out many smaller details because they assume im already familiar with the ORM to some degree.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the well detailed steps to have sequelize hook up to your Postgres instance, then define your models like they do in the docs... make sure you pay strict attention to setting up the associations in your models.. the belongsToMany was a bit tricky when I first tried it but if you have an trouble then post back here and I’ll show you where you may have gone wrong

Comment: I got TypeORM working. It seems to be alot simpler than sequelize as in it resembles JPA in some parts.

Comment: great news, i'll have to look into it.. Cheers!!